# Is the difference between "confidante" vs. "confident" the gender of the subject?

Tags: difference

I observe that the word *confidante* has *circa* 3,200<sup>1</sup> hits on The New York Times. And I also observe that on the same newspaper the word *confident* has *ca.* 148,000 hits.

3,200 seems to me a remarkable number. As is well known, *confidante* is used only for women, while *confident* is used both for men and women.

So the question is: Does this represent a persistent tendency to preserve sexism in language? Or are there cases in which *confidante* is preferable, for whatever reason?

<sup>1</sup>Searching from other countries could have different results.

Comment: I'm [confident](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/confident) that, in many of those 148,000 hits, the word being used as adjective, not as a noun.

Comment: If OP has accidentally misspelt the masculine form (which should be *confidant*), it's General Reference. But since that isn't a valid reason for closevoting, I'm going for Too Localised. FWIW, Google Books has 180 instances of ***she** is my confidant*, as against only 280 for ***he** is my confidant*, showing that many Anglophones don't bother with the gender-specific spelling anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree with closing as Too Localized.  This is a common mistake made by English Language Learners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with snailplane about leaving the question open. Still, I upvoted your comment because I appreciated your research and data.

Comment: The noun is *confidAnt*, isn't it? And I never knew it has a feminine version.

Comment: Although English has *fiancé* and *fiancée*, *blond* and *blonde*, *confidant* and *confidante*, *divorcé* and *divorcée*, etc., many people use such pairs interchangeably. Others use a single version (*blonde*, *divorcee*, etc.) for both genders.  So, I don't personally think it *is* well known, as you put it.

Comment: @Martha, yes, and Burchfield (1996), Canadian English Usage (1997) and Garner (1998) emphasize the need to use "confidante" for women only.

Comment: I feel this question goes (way) beyond the scope of ell. Should've probably been on en.se. It really does not help people who learn English as a second language.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: OK, but what do those usage guides say about always using *confidant*, regardless of gender? Like I said, I don't think I ever realized that the word *confidante* **exists**, and I certainly have never used it.

Comment: @Carlo_R., also, do you really and truly think the masculine version is *confident* with an E, or is that just a typo? If the former, this question needs to be closed as too localized. If the latter, please edit your question to fix the typo.

Comment: @James yes, perhaps I should have write the question giving more emphasis to the fact itself.

Comment: @Martha, I edited the question, but I could not make more than what I have done because there is already an answer to preserve.

Comment: I think it's better to preserve the error, because the confusion of "confidante" and "confident" is 1. common among ELLs and 2. caused the large disparity in number that led to the question.  Preserving the mistake will make the question easier to find for those who make the same error in the future.

Comment: @Martha, I tried editing this question, but since there is no agreement on the correction I rollbacked it into the earlier version. Then perhaps the better thing to do is voting to close.

Answer (score 13):

These are different words.

*Confidante* is a noun meaning ‘a person in whom one confides’. Both this, the feminine form, and the masculine form *confidant* without the feminine *-e* ending have been borrowed from French, in which language it derives from a participle. English preserves the gender distinction, which is not, I think, particularly sexist: the words are generally used of particular relationships in which it may be significant to distinguish male and female friends. It is, at any rate, no more sexist than the distinction between *boyfriend* and *girlfriend*.

*Confident* is an adjective, meaning ‘sure of oneself’ when used without modification, or *sure, trusting of [another]*. It is derived directly from Latin. Like other English adjectives, it is not inflected